# How to compose styled components in emotionjs with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I would like to do is to compose multiple styled components into one.

With plain css this is very easy:

```
<button class="btn large red"></button>
```

This is my attempt with emotion in React:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro";

const A = styled.button({
  color: "red"
});

const B = styled.button({
  fontSize: 32
});

// I know how to add single styled component. But how to also add B here?
const C = styled(A)({
  // some additional styles
});

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <A>A</A>
      <B>B</B>
      <C>C</C>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please check the demo:

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/98ykx2qo4p?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like `styled` is not capable of combining multiple styled components by default.

You might want to look at the `css` functionality of emotion [here](https://emotion.sh/docs/object-styles#composition). This allows the composition of multiple defined css styles. Even though this required more lines of code for the extra definition of the css objects.

Using `css` your example could look like this:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro";
import { css } from "@emotion/core";

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const red = css({
  color: "red"
});

const A = styled.button(red);

const bolt = css({
  fontSize: 32
});

const B = styled.button(bolt);

const C = styled.button(red, bolt);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <A>A</A>
      <B>B</B>
      <C>C</C>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/1rkpr85q74?fontsize=14)